# high interrupts

Tags: kernel, cpu

I have high Rescheduling interrupts and Local interrupts. while doing nothing my total CPU wakeups reach 275-400. While watching movies it reaches up 900-1000. And while browsing the Internet it reaches above 2000. 
Is it normal for ubuntu? 
Due to this i am experiencing overheating problem. 

I have tried using parameters noapic, pci=routeirq, pci=noacpi and acpi=off in grub but it didnt work. 
What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: And I am using jupiter.

Comment: Can we get some context for your conclusions? What tool did you use to determine the number of interrupts? How did you make a correlation between the number of interrupts and your system temperature?

Comment: i used powertop and system statistics to determine the number of interrupts. the CPU temperature is displayed by jupiter applet. and i monitored the CPU wakeups while doing nothing, playing videos and while browsing the internet